# Maximum depth of a circuit in IBM

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

Given Quantum Volume and number of qubits of a IBMQ device, what is the formula to calculate the maximum depth of the circuit that gives high fidelity?

For example: Let us consider `ibm_perth`, it has a Quantum Volume (`QV`) is 32 and number of Qubits (`Q`) is 7. What would be the depth limit of the circuit for this device to achieve high fidelity?

Comment: You should probably define way more precisely what you mean by "high fidelity" to get answers. And also note that the "fidelity" of a quantum circuit (in the sense "output state fidelity") does not only depend on its depth but also on: number of gates, gate error, idle time of qubits, SPAM errors, cross-talk errors,... (I might forget a few/lot)

Comment: The quantum volume actually helps you a little bit in order to know how good a computation might be, I would advise you to look at this : https://medium.com/qiskit/what-is-quantum-volume-anyway-a4dff801c36f, it explains well how it works and might give you ideas in this area.